# Apt unable to locate pacakge (grub-customizer) when its added through ppa [Ubuntu 23.04]

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, 23.04

Here's what I ran

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

Which successfully adds (and is able to `Hit:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu lunar InRelease`) the ppa
Then,

```
sudo apt update
```

Which updates successfully. But when I finally run

```
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

it results in `E: Unable to locate package grub-customizer`

I got the ppa link from [https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/%7Edanielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer). Its also available as a ppa for lunar, which I am currently using.

Comment: What is your architecture? Are you using Ubuntu for amd64 which includes 64 bit AMD and Intel, of course, or are you possibly using ARM?

Comment: Yeah, I am on 64 bit, and using amd64 iso, downloaded from this link https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=23.04&architecture=amd64.

Comment: The package for 23.04 [failed to build](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer/+packages).

Comment: Oh, alright. That makes sense...

Comment: Is there anything in particular that you wanted to customize about Grub? Grub customizer is known to be temperamental and it's often easier just to customize Grub manually. It's been a while since I've done it but it wasn't hard for me to manually change the background image, the background color, font color, and font type, etc. If you ask a question about what you would like to customize, like the background image for example, I'm sure someone could point you in the right direction.

Comment: As @mchid states, it can make it difficult to boot if there is an error in grub created by that tool... and I've noticed that some Ubuntu updates have made parts of the tool inoperative, e.g., changing font.